# SQL Server count number of distinct values in each column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ~150 columns.  I'd like to find the `count(distinct(colName))` for each column but am wondering if there's a way to do so without actually typing out each column name.

Ideally I would use `count(distinct(*))` but this doesn't work.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT:

if this is my table:

```
  id         col1         col2        col3      ...
  01         10001       west         north  
  02         10001       west         south  
  03         10002       east         south  
  04         10002       west         north  
  05         10001       east         south  
  06         10003       west         north
```

I'm looking for this output

```
count(distinct(id))   count(distinct(col1))    count(distinct(col2))   count(distinct(col3))
       6                       3                    2                      2
```

Comment: Wait is it possible to have a table with a single column name used more than once? Or do you have a field that stores a column name value?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max)
    SELECT @query = 
    'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' +'COUNT(DISTINCT(' + column_name + ')) 
             As ' + column_name + ' '  
             FROM information_schema.columns
             WHERE 
             table_name = 'table_name'
             for xml path('')),2,200000)  +  'FROM table_name'

PRINT(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below script to build T-SQL query that will return a distinct count of each column in a table. Replace `@Table` value with your table name.

```
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'TableName'; 

-- REVERSE and STUFF used to remove trailing UNION in string
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE((SELECT 'SELECT ''' + name 
                                     + ''' AS [Column], COUNT(DISTINCT(' 
                                     + QUOTENAME(name) + ')) AS [Count] FROM ' 
                                     + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' UNION ' 
                              -- get column name from sys.columns  
                              FROM   sys.columns 
                              WHERE  object_id = Object_id(@Table)
                              -- concatenate result strings with FOR XML PATH
                              FOR XML PATH (''))), 1, 7, ';'));
```

Comment: Great answer!  This orders the columns alphabetically, which doesn't work so well when there are lots (150) of columns. I will add an answer that builds on this one instead of editing this (for narrow tables this works well!).

Answer (score 1):

Expanded answer from Bryan.  His great answer lists the fields alphabetically.
This is no problem if you have a dozen fields or so. If you have 150 fields, like OP stated, this keeps the fields in their table's order.
I modified his query in order to examine a 213 column (vendor's) table and wanted to post for future reference.

```
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'Your table name; without schema; no square brackets'; 

-- REVERSE and STUFF used to remove trailing UNION in string
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE((SELECT 'SELECT ' 
        + CAST(column_id AS VarChar(4)) + ' AS [column_id],' -- extra column
        + '''' + name 
        + ''' AS [Column], COUNT(DISTINCT(' 
        + QUOTENAME(name) + ')) AS [Count] FROM ' 
        + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' UNION ' 
    -- get column name from sys.columns  
    FROM   sys.columns 
    WHERE  system_type_id NOT IN (34,240) AND object_id = Object_id(@Table) 
    ORDER BY column_id -- keeps columns in table order
    -- concatenate result strings with FOR XML PATH
    FOR XML PATH (''))), 1, 7, ';'));
```

I decided to not edit Bryan's answer because often people won't need the extra column.
(The ORDER BY has no effect if you don't add the column_id column. I believe this is because only the outermost ORDER BY is guarenteed to order the final output; I'd love to have a msft reference that confirms this)

EDIT:  Using function Count with field types Image and Geography throws error.
Added "system_type_id NOT IN (34,240)".

Comment: I wanted to wrap it all up into a single query using sp_executesql, but didn't have time.  I'll up-vote it if anyone posts that answer :–)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with just MySQL.
I would think your going to have to use a server side language to get the results you want.

Use "DESC TABLE" as your first query and then for each "field" row, compile your query.

---

Ignore this, wrong system tag :)

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct * from myTable) as t
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d411f/1) test.

```
create table Data
(
    Id int,
    Data varchar(50)
)

insert into Data 
select 1, 'ABC'
union all
select 1, 'ABC'

select count(*) 
from (select distinct * from Data) as t
```