# get a count of each value from every column in a table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I looked this up and this question is very similar but it's missing a key piece: [SQL Server count number of distinct values in each column of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625729/sql-server-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-each-column-of-a-table)

So in that question they want the distinct count for each column. What I am looking to do is to get a count of each distinct value for each column in a table (and I'm doing this for all the tables in a particular database which is why I'm looking to try to automate this as much as possible). Currently my code looks like this which I have to run for each column:

```
select mycol1, COUNT(*) as [Count] 
from mytable
group by mycol1
order by [Count] desc
```

Ideally my output would look like this:

```
ColumnName1 Count
val1        24457620
val2        17958530
val3        13350

ColumnName2 Count
val1        24457620
val2        17958530
val3        13350
val4 12
```

and so on for all the columns in the table

This answer below (provided by @beargle) from that previous question is *really* close to what I'm looking to do but I can't seem to figure out a way to get it to work for what I am trying to do so I would appreciate any help.

```
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'TableName'; 

-- REVERSE and STUFF used to remove trailing UNION in string
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE((SELECT 'SELECT ''' + name 
                                     + ''' AS [Column], COUNT(DISTINCT(' 
                                     + QUOTENAME(name) + ')) AS [Count] FROM ' 
                                     + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' UNION ' 
                              -- get column name from sys.columns  
                              FROM   sys.columns 
                              WHERE  object_id = Object_id(@Table)
                              -- concatenate result strings with FOR XML PATH
                              FOR XML PATH (''))), 1, 7, ';'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'TableName'; 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION SELECT ''' + name 
                            + ''' AS [Column], ' 
                            + 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                            + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ColumnValue], COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM ' 
                            + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                    FROM   sys.columns 
                    WHERE  object_id = Object_id(@Table)
                    -- concatenate result strings with FOR XML PATH
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 7, '');

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Which will produce SQL Like the following for a table with two columns (Column1 and Column2)

```
SELECT 'Column1' AS [Column], 
        CAST([Column1] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ColumnValue], 
        COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM    [TableName] 
GROUP BY [Column1] 
UNION 
SELECT  'Column2' AS [Column], 
        CAST([Column2] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ColumnValue], 
        COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM    [TableName] 
GROUP BY [Column2]
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want a new result set for each column then use:

```
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'TableName'; 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = (SELECT ' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                        + ', COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM ' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ';'
                FROM   sys.columns 
                WHERE  object_id = Object_id(@Table)
                -- concatenate result strings with FOR XML PATH
                FOR XML PATH (''));

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Which would produce SQL Like:

```
SELECT  [Column1], 
        COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM    [callsupplier] 
GROUP BY [Column1];

SELECT  [Column2], 
        COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM    [callsupplier] 
GROUP BY [Column2];
```

Comment: Let me suggest `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`, even though SQL Server could infer it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

thought i would take a stab at this whilst waiting for a backup to restore

hope this does what you require

```
create Table #Temp 
(tableName varchar(100),
columnName varchar(100),
value varchar(1000),
distinctItems int)

Declare @tabName as varchar(100)
Declare @colName as varchar(100)
Declare @tabid as int

Declare cursorTables Cursor
for 
select t.object_id , t.name , c.name from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on     t.object_id = c.object_id

open cursorTables 
Fetch Next from cursorTables into 
@tabid,@tabName,@colName


while @@Fetch_Status = 0 
Begin

declare @query as nVarchar(1000)
set @query  = 'Insert into #Temp SELECT    ''' + @tabName + '''  , '''+ @colName +''', '     + @colName + ',  COUNT([' + @colName +']) AS Expr1 FROM          [' + @tabName+ '] group by     [' + @colName + ']'
print @query
exec sp_executesql @query

Fetch Next from cursorTables into 
@tabid,@tabName,@colName


End 

Close cursorTables
Deallocate cursorTables

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

produces some not very useful results on PK values and i suspect it would not work on columns greater than varchar(1000) but works on a fe of my dbs

Answer (score 0):

This version makes a good snippet:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT ''' + t.name + ''', ''' + c.name + ''', ' + c.name + ', COUNT(' + c.name + ') AS C FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' GROUP BY ' + c.name + ';' + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
    WHERE s.name LIKE 'stage' AND t.name LIKE 'table' AND c.name LIKE '%whatever%';

--PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```