# How to get the most occurring values in each column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need some help with t-sql and I am new to SQL scripting.

I have a table with little over 70 columns and it is a datawarehouse. Some of values from the feeds are unknown values. For ex: if a date value is unknown, it will be 19000101 and emailkey = -1, while the default value might be NULL.

I need to write a script that retrieves the following information

Column 1 = Name of the column [This can be hard-coded or retrieved from a temp table]

Column 2 = the value that has the highest frequency of occurrence. [It can be NULL, a default value or some other valid value]. It will be the result of the following query: SELECT top 1 HotelKey AS countvalue from dbo.factBooking GROUP by HotelKey ORDER by count(*) desc

Column 3 = The count of the most frequently occurring value]. It will be the result of the following query: SELECT top 1  count(*) AS countvalue from dbo.factBooking GROUP by HotelKey ORDER by count(*) desc

Column 4 = This should show the percentage of column 3 against the total count]. It will be the result of the following query: (SELECT top 1 count(*)from dbo.factBooking GROUP by HotelKey ORDER by count(*) desc)/( SELECT count(*)from dbo.factBooking)

I want the query to compute the above value for all the columns in the table. Please let me know if I am not clear or if you need more information.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it work out? Are you having a problem with a specific query, or just looking for someone to write the query for you? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313615/get-a-count-of-each-value-from-every-column-in-a-table-sql-server - Try this

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not edited inside the question (you should be able to answer your own question)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Sorry about my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query to generate the data and it works fine:

use [Database Name]

DROP TABLE #tempcol

DROP TABLE #tempbigquery

CREATE table #tempbigquery (sqlquery varchar(max));

select ColID,Name As ColName  into #tempcol  from syscolumns where id=object_id('factFlights') ORDER BY  colid ASC
declare @Counter integer  = 1 , @ColCount Integer  = (select count(*) from #tempcol),@RowCount decimal(18,2)= (Select count(*) from dbo.factFlights)
Declare @colName  Varchar(100),@sqlquery NVarchar(max)   = ''
While @Counter < @ColCount+3
Begin

```
   Set @colName  =  (Select ColName from #tempcol where ColID = @Counter)
      if @colName IS not NULL
   Set @sqlquery  =  ISNULL('SELECT ColumnName,ColumnKey,CountValue,[Percent] FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 ' + Char(39) + @colName + char(39) + ' ColumnName,' + 'CAST(' + @colName + ' AS varchar(max))' + ' As ColumnKey,COUNT(*) AS CountValue,(COUNT(*) * 100.00) / ' + Cast( @RowCount   As Nvarchar(100)) + '  As [Percent] from dbo.factFlights GROUP by ' +  @colName + ' ORDER by count(*) desc ) As  ' + @colName + '_info  UNION  ' +   char(13),'')
      --Print @sqlquery
   Set @Counter  = @Counter + 1
      INSERT into #tempbigquery (sqlquery) VALUES (@sqlquery)
```

End

SELECT * FROM #tempbigquery