# Query Number of Populated Rows for Each Column in Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a count of non-null values for each column in my table.  I have researched the following previously asked SO questions, and have not found a satisfactory answer:

[Query to list number of records in each table in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database)

[get a count of each value from every column in a table SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313615/get-a-count-of-each-value-from-every-column-in-a-table-sql-server)

[SQL Server count number of distinct values in each column of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625729/sql-server-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-each-column-of-a-table)

I have written the following code to try to build out a data dictionary for my table to include the name of the column, the number of populated rows in each column, the data type, the length, and whether it is a primary key:

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    p.rows 'Row_Count',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.partitions p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID and i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('my_table')
```

However, the Row_Count column returns all Nulls.

My expected outcome looks like this:

```
Column_Name Row_Count Data_Type Max_Length Primary_Key
A              10       varchar   50            0
B              10       varchar   50            0
C              7        float     50            0
D              3        float     50            0
E              10       varchar   50            0
```

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a system view/function that will tell you how many non-NULLs a column has. You'll have to use dynamic SQL to `COUNT(Column)` for each column.

Comment: How do you want the data? 1 column per column, or 2 columns (Column Name and Count) and a row for every column?

Comment: My expected outcome is the column names in the first column, the count of populated rows in the second column, the type of data in the third, the length of the data in the fourth, and whether it's a primary key in the fifth

Comment: That's really important information, I think you need to actually show us the result set you want in your question. That's far more than *"I am trying to get a count of non-null values for each column in my table"*

Comment: you can check the nullability from system tables and if the column doesn't allow nulls use the rowcount from metadata but if the table has any columns allowing null you will have to query the table to get the count for those columns

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you show how I would write that query to use the rowcount from the meta data? I don't have Nulls in this table

Comment: @thedatasleuth take as look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836803/1744834. BTW, I think output format is a bit strange - if don't have nulls you don't have to count number of values for all columns - it will be the same for every column and should be equal number of rows in the table

Comment: @RomanPekar - just tried this one.  It looks like it should work but no values are returned. Thoughts?

Comment: @thedatasleuth sorry but I'm not going to guess why it doesn't work, create an example on sqlfiddle or dbfiddle and update the question, and I'm sure somebody will help you

Comment: I *think* I'm almost there with a solution here, but I won't say it's pretty. :/

Comment: which version of Sql Server do you use btw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option that does NOT use Dynamic SQL.

**Full disclosure**, I suspect DS would be more performant.   That said, this would work on any virtually any table, view or query.  I'm using `master..spt_values` as a demonstration

**Example**

```
Select ColumnName      = Item
      ,B.column_ordinal
      ,Row_Count       = sum(1)
      ,B.system_type_name
      ,B.max_length
      ,Distinct_Values = count(DISTINCT Value)
 From  (
        Select C.*
         From  master..spt_values A
         Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item  = replace(xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')
                              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                         From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                     ) C
       ) A
 Left Join  (
        Select * from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * from master..spt_values',null,null )  
       ) B on A.Item=B.name
 Group By A.Item
         ,B.system_type_name
         ,B.max_length
         ,B.column_ordinal 
 Order By B.column_ordinal
```

**Returns**

[image]

**EDIT**

As Larnu mentioned this will fail with (var)binary and image.   Again, this will NOT perform well on a large table.   I've only used such approaches during my discovery phase.

Comment: So this worked, but it did not return the results for all of my columns, just some of them - really not sure what's going wrong here

Comment: @thedatasleuth Did you adjust the the sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('...') ?

Comment: yes, i adjusted the table name in both places - the weird thing is, for the columns it did return, everything is perfect. any thoughts as to why it's skipping over some columns?

Comment: @thedatasleuth Are some columns completely NULL?   If so they would be excluded unless you make it an outer join

Comment: @thedatasleuth Columns begin with numbers or special characters?

Comment: the table I'm using your query on has no NULL values, however, it only returns 5 of the 73 columns in my table

Comment: @thedatasleuth Make it a LEFT JOIN.  Perhaps that will shed some light

Comment: Ok - the columns it's returning are the ones that are not separated by a space.  Is there a way to change the query to accommodate two word column names?

Comment: One note, this will fail if the table contains a `(var)binary` or `image` datatype. I do see what you mean by performant as well; against a large table it does appear struggle (at least on my little Home PC). Still +1

Comment: @Larnu Absolutely true... hence the "virtually"   :)

Comment: Yep, just thought it was worth giving an example of a table where it wouldn't.

Comment: @Larnu Fair enough.  I'll make the edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

God this is ugly...

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Table sysname = 'SampleTable';
DECLARE @Schema sysname = 'dbo';

SET @SQL = N'WITH Counts AS (' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'    SELECT @Schema AS SchemaName,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'           @Table AS TableName,' +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'           COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N') AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                  WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
                    AND C.TABLE_NAME = @Table
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,14,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N')' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'SELECT V.ColumnName,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'       V.NonNullCount,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'       ISC.DATA_TYPE + ISNULL(DT.S,'''') AS Datatype,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'       ISNULL(PK.IsPrimaryKey,''No'') AS PrimaryKey' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM Counts C' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'     CROSS APPLY(VALUES' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                                                      N'                       (N' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME,'''') + N',C.' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N')'
                                               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                               WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @Table
                                               FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,26,N'') + N')V(ColumnName,NonNullCount)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC ON C.SchemaName = ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                                        AND C.TableName = ISC.TABLE_NAME' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                                        AND V.ColumnName = ISC.COLUMN_NAME' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(''('' + STUFF(CONCAT('','' + CASE ISC.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH WHEN -1 THEN ''MAX'' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(4),ISC.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) END,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)+
           N'                                            '','' + CASE WHEN ISC.DATA_TYPE NOT LIKE ''%int'' THEN CONVERT(varchar(4),ISC.NUMERIC_PRECISION) END,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                                            '','' + CASE WHEN ISC.DATA_TYPE NOT LIKE ''%int'' THEN CONVERT(varchar(4),ISC.NUMERIC_SCALE) END,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                                            '','' + CONVERT(varchar(4),ISC.DATETIME_PRECISION)),1,1,'''') + '')'')) DT(S)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     OUTER APPLY(SELECT ''Yes'' AS IsPrimaryKey ' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                      JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU ON TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                                                                  AND TC.TABLE_NAME = KCU.TABLE_NAME' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                                                                  AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                 WHERE TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   AND KCU.COLUMN_NAME = V.ColumnName' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   AND TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   AND TC.TABLE_NAME = ISC.TABLE_NAME) PK;';

PRINT @SQL; --Might need to use SELECT here
--SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Schema sysname,@Table sysname',@Schema = @Schema, @Table = @Table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1795e955835b863501837868b9c342d5)

Honestly, there is a lot going on here. If it needs an explanation, I will try, but it will take some time, so (and no offence), i'm not going to put the effort in if no one is going to want/need to know.

*One note, I have been slightly lazy and no joined on `SCHEMA_NAME`. If you are using multiple schemas, with same named objects, this will have problem, and will need to be addressed.*

*Edit: apparently I'm a glutton for punishment. Fixed the Schema "problem" and added some logic in regards to ints*

*[New Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0cab6f2924607122ad206c812afbcd9)*

Comment: I see beauty in the care taken  +1

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti. Honestly, I think that took me too long though. :/ Heh